# OS X API to enumerate a folder including AppleDouble files (beginning with a "._")?

Tags: swift, macos, api, nsfilemanager, hidden-files

The following 4 NSFileManager API fail to enumerate AppleDouble files beginning with a "._"

enumeratorAtPath,
enumeratorAtURL,
contentsOfDirectoryAtPath,
contentsOfDirectoryAtURL

Which API should be used to get them enumerated without fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The below does the job, just in case someone needs it**

```
func contentsOfDirectoryUsingCAPI() -> [String]? {
    var contentsOfDirectory: [String]?

    if let folderPathCString = fileURL.path!.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        // Open the directory
        let dir = opendir(folderPathCString)

        if dir != nil {
            contentsOfDirectory = []

            // Use readdir to get each element
            var entry = readdir(dir)

            while entry != nil {
                let d_namlen = entry.memory.d_namlen
                let d_name = entry.memory.d_name

                // dirent.d_name is defined as a tuple with
                // MAXNAMLEN elements.  We want to convert
                // that to a null-terminated C string.                    
                var nameBuf: [CChar] = Array()
                let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: d_name)

                for _ in 0..<d_namlen {
                    for child in mirror.children {
                        if let value = child.value as? CChar {
                            nameBuf.append(value)
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Null-terminate it and convert to a String
                nameBuf.append(0)
                if let name = String.fromCString(nameBuf) {
                    contentsOfDirectory?.append(name)
                }

                entry = readdir(dir)
            }

            closedir(dir)
        }
    }

    return contentsOfDirectory
}
```